# Flutter GridView not scorlling properlly

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I am trying to use GridView in flutter and I am trying to use scroll so that the app bar and the filter buttons that I have above the GirdView would go up when I scroll down. However, the appbar is moving up when I scroll down but the filter buttons that I have above the GridView is not moving up. Please help me fix this problem. :(

This is Widget build

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: NestedScrollView(
    headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
      SliverAppBar(
        leadingWidth: 130,
        leading: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 15),
          child: ToggleButtons(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('남성', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
              Text('여성', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
            ],
            onPressed: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < _isGenderSelected.length; buttonIndex++) {
                  if (buttonIndex == index)
                    _isGenderSelected[buttonIndex] = true;
                  else
                    _isGenderSelected[buttonIndex] = false;
                }
              });
            },
            isSelected: _isGenderSelected,
            fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(43, 68, 112, 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          )
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
            '아바타 탐색',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            )
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(242, 244, 246, 1),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.refresh, color: Colors.black),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ]
      )
    ],
      body: SafeArea(
          minimum: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          //child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _filterAvatar(),
                    _avatarBar(),
                    _avatarImages()
                  ]
              )
          //)
      )
  ),
);
}
```

This is the filter buttons that I have above the GridView

```
Widget _filterAvatar() {
return Column(
  children: [
    Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Text('필터', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
    ),
    Row(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5, bottom: 5),
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_isFilterSelected[0] == false)
                      _isFilterSelected[0] = true;
                    else
                      _isFilterSelected[0] = false;
                  });
                },
                child: Text('피부색'),
                style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.grey,
                ),
            )
          )
        ),
        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5, bottom: 5, right: 3, left: 3),
            child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('쌍커풀'),
                    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.grey
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5, bottom: 5, right: 3, left: 3),
            child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('눈'),
                    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.grey
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5, bottom: 5),
            child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('얼굴형'),
                    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.grey
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
      ]
    ),
    Divider(color: Colors.grey)
  ]
);
}
```

And this is the GridView that I have under the filter button

```
Widget _avatarImages() {
return Expanded(
  child: GridView(
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
        child: Image.asset(_avatarList[0])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[1])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[2])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[3])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[4])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[5])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[6])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[7])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[8])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[9])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[10])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[11])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[12])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[13])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[14])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[15])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[16])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[17])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[18])
      ),
      Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          child: Image.asset(_avatarList[19])
      ),
    ],
  )
);
}
```